# Mongoid habtm selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am trying to figure out if there is a one liner to check to see if a pair is in the habtm

Conversation.in(participant_ids: [current_user.id, params[:recipient_id]]).first_or_create

So basically I need to check if a pair of [Sender, Receiver] or [Receiver, Sender] exists already. If so, return the conversation id. If not, create one.

I have tried .in, and .where, but they don't work all the time. Any ideas?

```
class Conversation
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_and_belongs_to_many :participants, :class_name => 'User'
  embeds_many :messages
end

def create
  @conversation = Conversation.any_of({participant_ids: [current_user.id, params[:recipient_id]]},
  {participant_ids: [params[:recipient_id], current_user.id]}).first

  if @conversation.nil?
    @conversation = Conversation.create(participant_ids: [current_user.id, params[:recipient_id]])
  end
  render json: { conversation_id: @conversation.id.to_s }
end
```

So this is the Model and method I have that is working, but it seems like there should be an easier way to do this.

Comment: Please include sample documents. Please also include everything you have tried and what doesn't work about it.

Comment: you can also use `document#first_or_initialize` instead of checking for `nil?`

Answer (score 0):

You got 2 possibilities

`scope :pair_exists, ->(pair){ where( :participant_ids.sort => pair.sort ) }`

`def self.pair_exists?(pair)
  where(:participant_ids.sort => pair.sort)
end`